# A specific markdown link doesn't render

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, markdown, markdown-rendering

In [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/posts/2434/revisions), my link for ISS isn't getting rendered correctly.

What's wrong?

Comment: If you just use the editor to add in a hyperlink it'll properly format the markdown for you.

Comment: I don't see a problem with the rendering... What do you mean by "incorrect rendering"?

Comment: @Werner I have since fixed it in a suggested edit.  See the previous revision.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You somehow got a weird character appended to the end of your ISS link. Viewing the source:

```
[1]: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MsHASky85cI
[Chris Hadfield]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chris_Hadfield
[ISS]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Space_Station‎&lrm;
```

The Markdown parser sees that left-to-right marker (`&lrm;`) and determines that your link is invalid and just doesn't render it.

Servy's edit didn't remove it either, just made it so that it was readable as a link:

```
[3]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Space_Station%E2%80%8E
```